# Using Kubectl API, read container start time from within pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver

To know the container start time, we generally describe the pod using:
`kubectl describe pod <pod-name>`. I need to access the container's start time via a kubectl api in terms of timestamp or any format. Do this exist in the API?

Comment: Why do you need this from within the pod itself?  Is it enough for the main container process to remember what time it was when it started, without doing anything Kubernetes-specific?

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze, this is required for websub(a module). I need to provide a URL from which the websub code can get the container start time. FYI, Websub do expect republish_time parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a `shell-script` for solving this problem, which follows up on info of pods from inside pod via kube APIs and parsing the same for required `lastTransitionTime` parameter:

```
APISERVER=https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
SERVICEACCOUNT=/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
NAMESPACE=$(cat ${SERVICEACCOUNT}/namespace)
TOKEN=$(cat ${SERVICEACCOUNT}/token)
curl -ik -H "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" ${APISERVER}/api/v1/namespaces/${NAMESPACE}/pods | grep "lastTransitionTime\:*[T]*\:*\:*" | tail -1
```

This script outputs the last restart time of pod (`tail -1`) for me.

Answer (score 2):

Effectively you could grab this via the status and state transitions. With kubectl it would look like this:

> kubectl get pod $PODNAME -o jsonpath='{.status.conditions[?(@.type=="Ready")].lastTransitionTime}'

would yield `2021-05-25T15:57:03Z` right now for me.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I was looking for this parameter `lastTransitionTime`, although i need it from inside pod. So, I have written a shell script for it following up kube APIs to be run inside pod, and i got the result.

Comment: @mac_55 you can sidecar a kubectl container and use it from there as a shell command. Otherwise as stated in your answer you can query the REST API alternatively.

Answer (score 0):

You could give the pod API access but that would be tricky (no easily policy way to say "access only to itself"). There is the Downward API volume system but I don't think it includes this field?